# How to insert ToolButton with menu in the header of QTableWidget in QT

Tags: qt

Can anybody please give me code to insert tool Button with menu in the  header of QTableWidget in QT

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to make your own QHeaderView subclass that paints the QToolButton and handles button presses, etc. You can then call myTableWidget->setHeader(instanceOfMyHeader) to use it in your QTableWidget.

Subclassing QHeaderView isn't exactly trivial. I've found a similar example that embeds a QCheckBox in the header, which can be found [here](https://projects.kde.org/projects/playground/sysadmin/apper/repository/revisions/master/entry/ApperKCM/Updater/CheckableHeader.cpp). (Replace .cpp with .h for the c++ header)

Hope this helps!

Comment: The first thing to do is to paint (in the paintSection method) the button in the toolbar. You can use QStyle to draw the style aware widget that looks like any other button in your application. You will however have to handle manually the related event (mouseClick) by redefining header methods. Also note that the appearance (pressed, etc.) of you button have also to be handled manually.